# is it possible to replace a substring to a dom element

Tags: php, regex, dom, str-replace

I have a situation here, i am a bit of java guy and getting some hard time with php.
I am creating an XML file from a database. For now, i created more than 90 dynamic elements, some includes attributes, child etc, w/o any problem. 
But things got messed up here;

text1:
`here is a list of pencils[1]. here is a list of another type of pencils[2].`

I do want to have

```
<text1>
```

`here is a list of pencils <id>1</id>. here is a list of another type of pencils <id>2</id>.`

`</text1>`

i can replace substrings ([1], [2]) and insert some other text, but how to replace these substrings with DOM element?

any help is deeply appreciated..

Comment: How are you building your XML document? With XMLwriter, or just plain string concatenation?

Comment: hi mhitza, thank you for your reply. i do use xml writer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because the string within you want to do the replacement is the `node Value` of the `text1` node. A variant would be to structure it like:

```
<text1>
  <partial>here is a list of pencils</partial>
  <id>1</id>
  <partial>.here is a list of another type of pencils</partial>
  <id>2</id>
</text1>
```

But honestly that is suboptimal.

I assume what got you confused (and me for a second there) is the way we write HTML:

```
<p>some text here <a href="...">a link</a> more <strong>variation</strong></p>
```

Which might give us the impression that it should be valid XML as well; but of course there is another thing to know; that browsers actually transform the prior HTML to the following form (~):

```
<p>
  <textnode>some text here </textnode>
  <a href="...">
    <textnode>a link</a>
  </a>
  <textnode> more </textnode>
  <strong>variation</strong>
</p>
```

Not the answer, but I'd recommend you rethink your XML format.

Comment: thanks mhitza.
well, i might be dreaming, but here is what i am working on..
- store the substring occurrences, and each location. 
- trim all substrings
- create an DOM element for each substring
- use end string for parent element.
how does that sound?